# Can different App Store publishers of an iOS App publish the same App with the same name in different territories?

Tags: ios, app-store

Can different publishers, which use different apple accounts, publish the very same app (same name, same bundle id) in different territories?

Like, you have one publisher for USA, and one for Asia?

If not, what steps need to be taken to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so
I think that You can submit a specific name or bundle ID only once
You can however set different pricing schemes if this is what You're aiming for
Or make two app versions; "App USA" and "App ASIA", and distribute them independently on desired teritories

Comment: This is what I thought as well, but found no real "evidence".
Somebody knows if it's possible to speak with Apple to achieve the above?